# Add value dictionary to a label after getting data from prepare segue

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

In the prepare segue, I add data to a dictionary in the other controller, here is that dictionary:

```
var data =  [String:String]()
```

and in prepare segue I add value and key to the dictionary

```
movieDetail.data.updateValue("title", forKey: self.animationItems[index!].snippet.title)

movieDetail.data.updateValue("description", forKey: self.animationItems[index!].snippet.description)
```

Is it right?

Then, there is an outlet in the new controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var movieTitle: UILabel!
```

this title should get the value(title) of the dictionary

I did that:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    movieTitle.text = data[title]?
}
```

but it shows an error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]' with an index of type 'String?'

Could you help me on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have been:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    movieTitle.text = data["title"]
}
```

You should have added the `""` to denote a string literal.

Your `prepareForSegue` is also wrong. The two arguments for `updateValue` are the other way around. To avoid confusion, you should just always use the `dict[key] = value` syntax:

```
movieDetail.data["title"] = self.animationItems[index!].snippet.title

movieDetail.data["description"] = self.animationItems[index!].snippet.description
```

Anyway, you should use a class/struct to represent your movies, then these problems will go away.

```
struct Movie {
    var title: String
    var description: String
}

// in MovieDetailController
var movie: Movie!

// in prepareForSegue
movieDetail.movie = Movie(title: self.animationItems[index!].snippet.title, description: self.animationItems[index!].snippet.description)

// in viewDidLoad
movieTitle.text = movie.title
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One more thing, could you show me, how I can save an array with these values in the userDefualt, I really need it

Comment: @Robert You probably shouldn't save it in User Default. User Defaults are for storing things like preferences. You should use a database for structured data like this. Try looking up tutorials on Core Data or use a library like [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest)

Comment: Yes I know that, but I work with a group that they want to save an array as favorite film in user defaults, I don't know why, but I have to do that

Comment: @Robert Oh well... That really sucks. You can conform `Movie` to `Codable` and use `JSONEncoder` to convert the movie to `Data`, which you can then save to User Defaults. You can then use `JSONDecoder` to decode the `Data` back to a `Movie`.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it